# Renaming or creating a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a number of data frames which take their name from a list.

eg.

```
mylist <- c("home", "work", "pub")
for (i in mylist) {
    name <- i
    Hourly  <<- ddply(get(i), .(week = week(StartTime), Place = name)
}
```

This produces 1 dataframe called Hourly with week and name variables.

What I want is 3 dataframes called home_hourly, work_hourly, pub_hourly each containing their respective 2 variables.  How do I produce 3 dataframes, prefixing each with name?

Comment: you could use `assign`, but don't - just keep them in a list

Comment: Parenthesis are not matching in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a combination of the assign() function and the paste() function.

```
mylist <- c("home", "work", "pub")
for (i in mylist) {
    name <- i
    assign(paste(name, "hourly", sep = "-"), ddply(get(i), .(week = week(StartTime), Place = name))
}
```

Comment: Using `sep="-"` will create problematic names, that can only be referenced with backticks.

Comment: Thank you for your responses - they are all appreciated - but perhaps some were a bit quick to mark as duplicate?

'How to name variables on the fly in R?" does indeed answer the question of creating a named variable but not the dynamic population of each variable.

For that you do need paste and assign:

`for (i in mylist) {`

`onThisI <- paste(i,"Unit",sep="_")`

`assign(onThisI, ddply(get(i), .(week = as.factor(week(StartTime)), Unit = i))
}`